# ASP.Net Core, the localhost cannot be found on Macbook

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, macos, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

I'm having a strange problem with my ASP.Net Core application. When I run in on localport from my Macbook, the project is building, but in the broser i'm seeing only this error.

> This localhost page can’t be foundNo web page was found for the web address: https://localhost:5001/
> HTTP ERROR 404

My question is from where that problem occurs and what is the reason for it? I'll attach my github repo to check the code if you are fine. https://github.com/ddxkalin/MovieDatabase

Comment: Hi @Rena! After your changes everything is working fine now, only the Front-end libraries like bootstrap and others are a bit messed up, because the project is a bit old, but thanks to you, everything from the back-end logic is working! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary:

Your current problem 404 caused by you comment out the route template. But if you use the route template, you will get a new problem that method not found because your **Web** project is `.net core3.1` which uses `SigninManager` with package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity 3.1.0`, while your **Services** project is `.netstandard 2.0` which uses `SigninManager` with`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity 2.2.0`. This will causes the method not found. The two different version package uses two different constructor of the SigninManager.
SigninManager in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity 2.2.0`:

```
public class SignInManager<TUser> where TUser : class
{ 
    public SignInManager(UserManager<TUser> userManager, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser> claimsFactory, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, ILogger<SignInManager<TUser>> logger, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes);
```

SigninManager in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity 3.1.0`:

```
public class SignInManager<TUser> where TUser : class
{ 
    public SignInManager(UserManager<TUser> userManager, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser> claimsFactory, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, ILogger<SignInManager<TUser>> logger, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes,
                                      IUserConfirmation<TUser> confirmation);
```

---

In `MovieDatabase.Web` Project, you should use route template below:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoint =>
{
    endpoint.MapControllerRoute("admin", "{area:exists}/{controller=Dashboard}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoint.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoint.MapRazorPages();
});
```

In `MovieDatabase.Services` project, change your project file and `ApplicationSignInManager.cs` like below:

1.change `TargetFramework` to `netcoreapp3.1` and add `FrameworkReference` of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
 
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />

  <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.6.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="StyleCop.Analyzers" Version="1.1.0-beta009" PrivateAssets="all">
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

2:Change the `ApplicationSignInManager.cs`:

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager<TUser> : SignInManager<ApplicationUser>
    where TUser : ApplicationUser
{
    public ApplicationSignInManager(
        ApplicationUserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
        IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
        ILogger<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>> logger,
        IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemeProvider,
        IUserConfirmation<ApplicationUser> userConfirmation       //add this...
    )
    : base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger, schemeProvider, userConfirmation)
    {
    }
```